# Writing a filter predicate: "expression has type int .. expected of type bool"

Tags: ocaml

So I wrote a function "filter" that is applied to the given predicate to each element in the input list and checks whether it should be included in the output.

```
let rec filer (pred: 'a -> bool) (l: 'a list) : 'a list =
begin match l with
| [] -> []
| hd :: rest -> if (pred hd) then hd :: (filter pred rest) else filter pred rest
end
```

Now I'm writing a predicate that can be passed to filter to keep just multiples of five.

```
let multiples_of_five_pred: int -> bool =
filter (fun (x: int) -> x mod 5)
```

I don't know what I'm missing here...I'm getting a syntax error that says "this expression has type int but an expression was expected of type bool".

Comment: Well, what *is* the compiler trying to say? :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function given to `filter` needs to produce an boolean, but as the error message is telling you, the function you give to `filter` produces an integer, not a boolean. You need to change it to produce a boolean instead.

Once you fix that, you'll have another type error: Applying `filter` to a function that takes an integer will produce a function of type `int list -> int list`, but according to your type signature, you want the type `int -> bool`.

Also note that you say that `multiples_of_five_prod` should be a function that is *given* to `filter`, but you actually call `filter` inside the function. That doesn't fit. You should remove the call to `filter`.

Answer (score 0):

The root of the problem is that you're using type annotations when you don't need to. If you missed them out (they're not needed), you would see more quickly why your second function doesn't have the type that you expect.

Comment: Well, I'd say that he's already getting a message that indicates the exact problem :-)  The trick (maybe) is to believe the compiler. I don't think using type annotations should necessarily be discouraged.

Comment: The problem isn't that the second function has a wrong type. It doesn't have a type at all - it's ill-typed. It won't compile with or without type annotations. Also removing type annotations rarely leads to more helpful error messages and in this case the error message won't change at all.